# c# run application as another user fails with System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception

Tags: c#

I work with emergency services and they have an application that uses map files to let them know where they need to go and it uses GPS to let them know where they are. We have to update the map files as things change and before I started here they were being done through VB scripts which started to fail. I decided to code my own app in C# to do this which works fine.

I created a package in SCCM 2012 that caches all of the files locally and then it compares the files in the cache to what is on the machine and then replaces any older files. This all works fine but the application they use called MobileCAD locks the files so I have to kill this process and then do the file copy and start the application again. We never know when an emergency happens so this update may start when they are on the road so it is important that it starts the application again as soon as possible. If it does not start the application then the emergency services people may try to do so manually but if core files are being updated then it may not start or cause issues.

I coded my application which uses an app manifest to force it to run as an administrator for the file copy. This application is run through SCCM which uses the local 'System' account to do all of the work and killing MobileCAD and copying files which works great. What I originally found was that it does start MobileCAD but it does so under the System account and the process would be there but it was not visible. I think this is the same problem they were originally having so the emergency services people would need to reboot the computer and wait for it to log back in and then start the wireless service so they could get back into MobileCAD.

To address this issue I did research and found that I could use the ProcessStartInfo in .NET and force it to use another account. As we use an automatic logon for these machines the users name, password, and domain are all in the registry so it was easy to pull it out and inject it into the code. Awesome, looks like it is easy enough so I code it up and sure enough it works perfectly when run under my admin account. In my basic testing everything worked perfectly until I try the same in SCCM, now it fails with the following error message.

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access is denied
at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo    startInfo)
at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
at UpdateFDM.Program.StartProcess(String processName)
```

I am sorry for all of the words but I believe it helps if you have a good understanding of the issue and what I am trying to do. I have also hard coded the user information into the code instead of pulling it from the registry but I get the same error. Again, this works fine under my admin account but fails when it is pushed through SCCM and it is only launching MobileCAD that fails.

This is the code I am using for launching MobleCAD, do you see where my issue may lie? I know SCCM confuses it but SCCM basically runs things just as you would from the command line but it uses the local System account.

Thanks for any help.

```
// Declares the new start instance
ProcessStartInfo process = new ProcessStartInfo();

// Gets the process to start
process.FileName = processName;
// Maximizes the process windows at start-up
process.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;

// Gets the user name from the autologon information
process.UserName = GetDefaultUserInfo("DefaultUserName");
// Gets the domain for the user
process.Domain = GetDefaultUserInfo("DefaultDomainName");

// Holds the password for the default user
SecureString password = new SecureString();
// Gets the raw password from the registry
string rawPassword = GetDefaultUserInfo("DefaultPassword");

// Copies the password in a secure string
foreach (char ch in rawPassword)
{
    password.AppendChar(ch);
}

// Sets the password
process.Password = password;

// Needed to launch the app as the logged on user
process.LoadUserProfile = true;
process.UseShellExecute = false;

// Starts the process
Process.Start(process);

// Process started, return true
return true;
```

Comment: So to clarify you're using the current user login information and this isn't working when logging in from a non-admin user?

Comment: If I start MobileCAD from the standard user account it works fine. If I run my app using my elevated admin account the updates happen and MobileCAD opens and works properly. When I use SCCM to push out my app the file transfers are done properly but MobileCAD won't launch and gives the access denied error message.

Comment: What is the value of `processName` during the times it fails? Also do you set `process.WorkingDirectory`? [See the remarks section](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.password(v=vs.110).aspx) of the Password property of StartInfo

Comment: Hi Scott, I was not using the process.WorkingDirectory so I added this and then pointed it to the MobileCAD directory where the users have full control and it failed with the same error when run by SCCM. I then went into the SCCM cache and ran the same application with my admin rights and it shut down MobileCAD and then started it right back up. I have checked name, password, and domain and they are all correct. I can see MobileCAD is running under the users name and it only fails when SCCM is running it through the System account.

Comment: I have checked and confirmed and processName is showing the proper path to the executable as this is hard coded into the application so it is not picking it up through the system.

Comment: I have no idea why this is not working but I believe it is due to the System account being local and the user account being a domain account. As a work-around for what I need I spilt the applications so now there are two that are chained together through SCCM. The first one runs with admin rights and does all of the file synchronization and then the second app simply starts MobileCAD with the users rights. I still have to load these in SCCM and do more testing but it should do what I need it to do.